# React-Router returns 404 on child routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm using react, react-router(v4), redux and webpack(-dev-server) to build an app. The Devserver and eveything works fine, including HMR and `historyApiFallback`. Means that when I enter `http://localhost:8080/how` I get `index.html`, `bundle.js` (my app), and the right component `How` is being rendered.

My basic Routing looks as followed:

```
//App.js 
<Router>
    <Wrapper>
        <Route path='/' component={MainNav} />
        <Route exact path='/' component={Splash} />
        <Route path='/how' component={How} />
        <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
        <Route path='/' component={Footer} />
    </Wrapper>
```

However, when declaring a child route, e.g. in `Auth`:

```
<Wrapper orange>
    Login Page
    <Link to={loginUrl}>Login</Link>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/auth/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
    </Switch>
</Wrapper>
```

I get a 404 from react-router when entering `http://localhost:8080/auth/login`. When navigating to `http://localhost:8080/auth/login` within the App, e.g. on a Link click, the `Login` Component is being rendered.

I know there are a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow, but the strange thing is that top-level Routes are being rendered without a problem, this occurs only on nested routes. Also, it's probably not a problem with webpack-dev-server (`historyApiFallback` or `publicPath`), because I can also bundle the app for production and serve it with a node server, same result.

Also I dont see a difference to the [basic example in the react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

FYI, here is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    context: resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    entry: debug ? [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './index.js',
    ] : './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',

        path: resolve(__dirname, 'public'),

        publicPath: '/',
        // necessary for HMR to know where to load the hot update chunks
    },

    // possibly change to inline-source-map or something else
    devtool: debug ? 'eval' : false,

    devServer: debug ? {
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
    } : { },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: [
                    'babel-loader',
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?modules',
                    'postcss-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },

...
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be sure that your server environment knows to forward all requests to the index.html file, this is dependent upon the build environment and server setup.

Comment: You can look into how [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) achieves this for more info.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that already. In `webpack-dev-server` normally `historyApiFallback` would do that. In node the last route is something like this: `app.use('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile('index.html') }

Comment: Does it return 404 on getting index.html or on getting .js/.css files?

Comment: @GProst both, the node server as well as the webpack-dev-server return the requested file (e.g. `index.html`, `bundle.js`). I don't have css files, since I'm using `styled-components`, but assets, e.g. images, are being served as expected.